# ¿Como puedo obtener el texto de las columnas de un DataView en C#?

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview

Quiero usar la información de unas columnas para introducirla en otra columna.
Los campos me aparecen vacíos porque siempre se queda en la primera fila y quiero que vaya cambiando a la siguiente en cada vuelta del foreach, el evento ocurre cuando le doy al botón de enerar_configurable_variation que es el que me insertará esa información en otra columna

````
       {
           try
           {
               string configurable_variations = "";

              foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvrow in dataGridView2.Rows)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show(dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells["temperatura_color"].Value.ToString(), "Error Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                   

                   configurable_variations += "sku=" + dgvrow.Cells["sku"].Value.ToString(); //sku

                   if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells["conector"].Value.ToString()))
                   {
                       configurable_variations += ",conector=" + dgvrow.Cells["conector"].Value.ToString(); //P1
                   }

                   if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells["temperatura_color"].Value.ToString()))
                   {
                       configurable_variations += ",temperatura_color=" + dgvrow.Cells["temperatura_color"].Value.ToString(); //temperatura_color
                   }

                   if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells["angulo"].Value.ToString()))
                   {
                       configurable_variations += ",angulo=" + dgvrow.Cells["angulo"].Value.ToString(); //angulo
                   }

                   if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells["acabado"].Value.ToString()))
                   {
                       configurable_variations += ",acabado=" + dgvrow.Cells["acabado"].Value.ToString(); //acabado
                   }

                   dgvrow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Khaki;
                   configurable_variations += "|";

                   if (dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells["product_type"].Value.ToString() == "configurable")
                   {
                       dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Cells["configurable_variations"].Value = configurable_variations;
                   }
               }

               configurable_variations = configurable_variations.Remove(configurable_variations.Length - 1, 1);
               richTextBox1.Text = configurable_variations;
           }
      
         catch (Exception ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
               MessageBox.Show("Producto no encontrado", "Error Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
           }

       }```

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzS0y.png
````

Comment: usas indistintamente dataGridView2.CurrentRow y dgvrow.. ahi esta el problema, es todo confuso...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres obtener la información de una columna en un Datagridview debes usar un foreach El código seria así:

```
string[] informacion = new string[Datagridview.Rows.Count];
int r = 0;
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in Datagridview.Rows)
  {
    RUTAS[r] = row.Cells[0].Value != null ? 
    row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
    r++;
}
```

Para introducir la información en otra columna solo usa un for usando el tamaño de tu Datagridview y Ncolumna sera la columna que se editara en la programacion se empieza usando el 0 siendo por ejemplo el 2 la columna 3 el 5 en columna 6, ten encuenta eso. El codigo seria así:

```
int N_Filas = Convert.ToInt32(Datagridview.RowCount.ToString()) - 1;
int NColumna = 2;
for(int i = 0 ; i< N_Filas ; i++)
{
string data = informacion[i]
Datagridview[NColumna, i].Value = ""+data;
}
```